# executing jarsigner command generates error: "Jarsigner is not recognized internal or external command"

Tags: jboss, jarsigner

I am trying to verify signature of apk uploaded on my site.
I am trying to execute

```
String command= "cmd /c jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs " +Filelocation;
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader reader1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
String line=reader.readLine();  
String line1=reader1.readLine();
```

line output is null and line1 output is"Jarsigner is not recognized internal external command".

I have checked java_home,java.home,java.class.path.
java_home is holding jdk path
java.home is holding jre path
java.class.path holds jboss server>deploy folder.

I am running this part of code on JBOSS Server.

Comment: Duplicate question, answer here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33132310/jarsigner-is-not-recognized-internal-or-external-command

Answer (score 8):

Make sure Java JDK is set on the PATH. In my case put "D:\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\bin" into System Variable PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the release key and the apk are in the same directory.

Comment: consider using comments to ask more info about the question.

Answer (score 0):

## 1 Make sure below Environment Variables are set:

Variable name: `JAVA_HOME`
Varaible value: `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7` (example only; update path based on your Java library location)

Variable name: `Path`
Varaible value: `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;`

## 2 Make sure that jarsigner.exe file exists in your JAVA library ie.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\jarsigner.exe
```