# Jarsigner is not recognized internal or external command

Tags: android, apk, jarsigner

i'm trying to check if my signed release apk is really signed.
But following some tutorials, or the single i've found .

```
$ jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs my_application.apk
```

I am receiving this message : "Jarsigner is not recognized internal external command".

Remembering that my apk is in the same folder of jarsigner.exe
I dont know what to do.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**Solution:** Add android jdk bin folder to your path in environment variables.

***Instructions:***

1- Right click on "This PC" > right-click Properties > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables > select PATH then EDIT.

2- Add your jdk bin folder path to environment variables, it should look like this:

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin".

Comment: Now is working with some modifications :  jarsigner.exe -verify -verbose -certs c:\MainActivity-release.apk

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to My computer -> right click -> system properties ->select environmental variables ->Edit Path ->
   add your jdk/bin path and  select ok. The sample jdk path is as shown below.

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin

*if this not work then

2. In command prompt set the path by using the below command

set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin

now the path is set now you can use the jarsigner

Comment: set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin it works!

Answer (score 3):

If the above step does not work, copy the unsigned-release-apk.apk file and keystore file in C:\Program Files\java\jdk_version\bin\ and run cmd as an administrator and navigate to C:\Program Files\java\jdk_version\bin\

Now your jarsigner will work successfully.

Comment: @MohammadAyoubKhan did you run cmd as an administrator

Comment: I was using two versions of java JDK I removed one and added scond JDK bin folder path to environment variables. Then tried `jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore myapp-key.keystore myapp.apk myapp`, It successfully worked now.

Answer (score -2):

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\".
if you this instead of the above thread it will take all the functions in the bin area e.g keytool and certifier as well